# How to get un-versioned files included while deploying serverless apps via github actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, github-actions

I have a serverless project which requires SSL signed cert/private key for communication to an API. The cert/key aren't in version control, but locally are in my file system. The files get bundled with the lambdas in the service and are accessible for use when deployed.

```
package: 
  individually: true
  include:
    - signed-cert.pem
    - private-key.pem
```

Deployment is done via Github Actions.
e.g. `npm install serverless ... npx serverless deploy`

How could those files be included without adding them to version control? Could they be retrieved from S3? Some other way?

It looks like [encrypting the files](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets) may work, but is there a better approach? The lambdas could fetch them from S3, but I'd rather avoid additional latency on every startup if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like adding a GitHub secret for the private key and certificate works. Just paste the cert/private key text into a GitHub secret e.g.

Secret: SIGNED_CERT, Value: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----......-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

Then in the GitHub Action Workflow:

```
  - name: create ssl signed certificate
    run: 'echo "$SIGNED_CERT" > signedcert.pem'
    shell: bash
    env:
      SIGNED_CERT: ${{secrets.SIGNED_CERT}}
    working-directory: serverless/myservice
  - name: create ssl private key
    run: 'echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private-key.pem'
    shell: bash
    env:
      PRIVATE_KEY: ${{secrets.PRIVATE_KEY}}
    working-directory: serverless/myservice
```

Working directory if the serverless.yml isn't at that root level of the project.